# What is best way to record a doublebass in a home studio enviroment?

Tags: recording, microphone, home-studio, signal-processing

What is best way to record a [Doublebass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bass) in a home studio enviroment?

What type of mic?

What kind of processing? (compression? eq?)

[image: Double bass]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a session coming up and have been reading a lot about this to.
The strangest yet most practical and cheaper technique, is a sm57 with the body and cable wrapped in a washcloth tucked in the bridge aiming upwards.
(the washcloth is so that you can fit the mic into the bridge)

http://www.gearslutz.com/board/remote-possibilities-acoustic-music-location-recording/474365-unusual-upright-bass-micing-technique.html
lots of ideas there

Fun :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. this might actually do the trick for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

My favourite way is with an Rode NT1A pointed at the player's left f hole just over 12"s away.  If I am capturing it live on a stage I will use an Audio-Technica AT803b attached using the tieclip to the strings, just below the bridge.  This also works for cello, viola and violin.   With regards to processing, some gentle compression and a light touch of reverb is usually more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late on this one, but I'll mention it anyway. I wasn't sure what kind of music you're playing, but I can comment about jazz more than classical. I've played with guys who loved [these](http://www.zzounds.com/item--FSMPBP100B) kinds of double bass pickups. There are dozens out there, usually between $100-300. As for EQ, I prefer subtle touches, just enough to compliment the bass's natural sound. I would mic the neck as well, but that's 'cause I really like hearing the slap of the strings.